# stackoverflowで改行入力どうするの？

Tags: サポート, markdown

stackoverflowで入力画面で改行しても改行されない。改行したい。

Comment: meta stackoverflowなんてあったんですね。知りませんでした

Answer (score 8, accepted):

公式のマークダウンヘルプがありますのでそちらの方がいいでしょう。

[Markdown ヘルプ(https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

> ## 改行
>
> 行末にスペースを 2 個入れると、`<br/>` 改行が追加されます:

Comment: 直接`<br/>`を入れても大丈夫ですが、（半角）スペース2個の方が便利な気がします。

Answer (score 1):

```
半角スペースを二つ入力する[][]と改行される。
```

↓

```
半角スペースを二つ入力する
と改行される。
```

その他マークダウン記法は下記を参照
http://kojika17.com/2013/01/starting-markdown.html